# How to create plugin to override a magento2 module?

Tags: magento2, plugin

I can not override a protected function using plugin. iS there any other way to override the same function?

Comment: you can use override like as controller model we did without plugin

Comment: Check this stack, it explains how you can override a protected function in the correct way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241663/magento-2-how-to-override-protected-funtion-in-abstract-class

Answer (score 2):

You can not override protected function using plugin.

**Plugin Limitations**:

Plugins cannot be used with any of the following:

```
Final methods
Final classes
Non-public methods
Static methods
__construct
Virtual types
Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped
Objects that are not instantiated by the ObjectManager (e.g. by using new directly).
```

For More Details refer Magento Devdoc

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

In your case, you can use Preference to override these classes which have protected mathod.